# Single PV mount on all members of Replica Set for a K8s deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims

I would like to understand if there is a way to mount a single PV that I manually created with ReadWriteMany to all the members of the replicaSet either using PodSpec or StatfulSet.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Did Harsh Manvar solution help you to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do if your PV is supporting the **ReadWriteMany**.

Here sharing the YAML for example

**PVC**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - sh
        image: busybox
        name: busybox
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc
          mountPath: "/mnt"
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test-claim
```

Comment: So I did try it this way on my 3 pod deployment, however what I observe is that 1 volume gets created on each of the 3 nodes for the 3 pods, If I scale the deployment the newer pods will fail because there is already a volume on the nodes which is being used by the existing pods. I am using k3d with 3  agent nodes.

Comment: that;s weird could you share the screenshot in question ? please share describe output also if pod failing